# Cancelling pthread_cond_wait() hangs with PRIO_INHERIT mutex

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex, embedded-linux

*Update, 4/10 2012:*
[Fixed by libc patch](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=55a051c985c3e7965a2f5dd5f762ac2737adae01)

---

I have a problem canceling threads in `pthread_cond_wait`, that use mutexes with the `PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT` attribute set. This only happens on certain platforms though.

The following minimal example demonstrates this: (compile with `g++ <filename>.cpp -lpthread`)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void clean(void *arg) {
    std::cout << "clean: Unlocking mutex..." << std::endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock((pthread_mutex_t*)arg);
    std::cout << "clean: Mutex unlocked..." << std::endl;
}

void *threadFunc(void *arg) {
    int ret = 0;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
    ret = pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexAttr); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;

    //Comment out the following line, and everything works
    ret = pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;

    ret = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mutexAttr); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;
    ret = pthread_cond_init(&cond, 0); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;

    std::cout << "threadFunc: Init done, entering wait..." << std::endl;

    pthread_cleanup_push(clean, (void *) &mutex);
    ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;
    while(1) {
        ret = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    int ret = 0;
    ret = pthread_create(&thread, 0, threadFunc, 0); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;

    std::cout << "main: Thread created, waiting a bit..." << std::endl;
    sleep(2);

    std::cout << "main: Cancelling threadFunc..." << std::endl;
    ret = pthread_cancel(thread); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;

    std::cout << "main: Joining threadFunc..." << std::endl;
    ret = pthread_join(thread, NULL); std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;

    std::cout << "main: Joined threadFunc, done!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run it, `main()` hangs on `pthread_join()`. A gdb backtrace shows the following:

```
Thread 2 (Thread 0xb7d15b70 (LWP 257)):
#0  0xb7fde430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7fcf362 in __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/lowlevellock.S:142
#2  0xb7fcc9f9 in __condvar_w_cleanup () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/pthread_cond_wait.S:434
#3  0x08048fbe in threadFunc (arg=0x0) at /home/pthread_cond_wait.cpp:22
#4  0xb7fc8ca0 in start_thread (arg=0xb7d15b70) at pthread_create.c:301
#5  0xb7de73ae in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:130

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb7d166d0 (LWP 254)):
#0  0xb7fde430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7fc9d64 in pthread_join (threadid=3083950960, thread_return=0x0) at pthread_join.c:89
#2  0x0804914a in main () at /home/pthread_cond_wait.cpp:41
```

If `PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT` isn't set on the mutex, everything works as it should, and the program exits cleanly.

Platforms with problems:

- Embedded AMD Fusion board, running a [PTXDist](http://www.ptxdist.org/software/ptxdist/index_en.html) based 32-bit Linux 3.2.9-rt16 (with [RTpatch](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) 16). We are using the newest [OSELAS](http://www.ptxdist.de/oselas/toolchain/index_en.html) i686 cross toolchain (2011.11.1), using gcc 4.6.2, glibc 2.14.1, binutils 2.21.1a, kernel 2.6.39.
- Same board with the 2011.03.1 toolchain also (gcc 4.5.2 / glibc 2.13 / binutils 2.18 / kernel 2.6.36).

Platforms with no problems:

- Our own ARM-board, also running a PTXDist Linux (32-bit 2.6.29.6-rt23), using OSELAS arm-v4t cross toolchain (1.99.3) with gcc 4.3.2 / glibc 2.8 / binutils 2.18 / kernel 2.6.27.
- My laptop (Intel Core i7), running 64-bit Ubuntu 11.04 (virtualized / kernel 2.6.38.15-generic), gcc 4.5.2 / eglibc 2.13-0ubuntu13.1 / binutils 2.21.0.20110327.

I have been looking around the net for solutions, and have come across a few patches that I've tried, but without any effect:

- [Making the condition variables priority inheritance aware.](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11588)
- [Handling EAGAIN from FUTEX_WAIT_REQUEUE_PI](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=c5a0802a682dba23f92d47f0f99775aebfbe2539)

Are we doing something wrong in our code, which just happens to work on certain platforms, or is this a bug in the underlying systems? If anyone has any idea about where to look, or knows of any patches or similar to try out, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Thanks!

*Updates:*

- [libc-help mailing list discussion](http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2012-08/msg00003.html)
- [glibc bug report](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14477)

Comment: `pthread_cleanup_push((void(*)(void*))pthread_mutex_unlock, (void *) &mutex);` is broken. You can't cast a function pointer like that. You need to write a wrapper function and pass the address of the wrapper. (By the way, on my Linux box, this works in a 64-bit program but fails in a 32-bit program. This is true whether or not `pthread_mutex_unlock` is properly wrapped.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated the code example to use a wrapper - sadly it makes no difference on neither our embedded board (still doesn't work, never enters the cleanup handler) nor my laptop (still works, runs cleanup just fine). Interesting that it works on 64 bit but not on 32 bit though, I'll have a look into that.

Comment: @David, it's UB, yes, but in the case of x86_64 it's not what's breaking it. The argument number, register types, and representations match.

Comment: I suspect this may be related to glibc (NPTL) bug number 14417: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14417

Comment: Thanks! The commit that the bug refers to isn't introduced in the glibc's that we're using and that exhibit the problem though (the commit is in glibc 2.15, we're using 2.13 / 2.14.1) - I've already had a look at a related issue though, and actually manually applied the commit in question to my glibc 2.13 (as stated in the question) because it sounded as if it might have something to do with it. It didn't have any effect though, but I might try posting in the glibc bug system. From the dates, it seems as if it's something they're looking at currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, glibc's condition variable implementation is rotten to the core. It's been fundamentally broken and known to be fundamentally broken, for well over a year now.

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't exactly sound encouraging. If you have links to any discussions or similar on the topic, I'd be very interested!

Comment: Small followup, I've been directed to file a bug report with glibc - it can be found here: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed by a [libc patch](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=55a051c985c3e7965a2f5dd5f762ac2737adae01). 
I've confirmed it to work on my own problematic platform (our custom AMD Fusion board), patched onto glibc-2.14.1.

Thanks go out to Siddhesh Poyarekar for the fix!