# How do I debug a mutex that is not locking

Tags: c++, mutex, deadlock

I am trying to figure out why is my thread not acquiring the lock

```
const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutexPublish);
```

Using gdb at the hanging point I have the following backtrace

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000007fb7f8e690 in __lll_lock_wait (futex=futex@entry=0x7fffffe048, private=0) at lowlevellock.c:46
#1  0x0000007fb7f877c8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fffffe048) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
#2  0x0000005555596c78 in __gthread_mutex_lock (__mutex=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:748
#3  0x0000005555596c78 in std::mutex::lock() (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_mutex.h:103
#4  0x0000007facc845f4 in Client::publish(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) () at ...
#5  0x0000007facc89490 in ... at ...
#6  0x0000005555590ca4 in ... (this=0x7fffffd960) at ...
#7  0x0000005555572c18 in main() at ...
```

After that I tried to get more information on the mutex

```
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0000007fb7f877c8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fffffe048) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
80  pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print mutex
$2 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0x7fffffe048
(gdb) $2.__data
Undefined command: "$2".  Try "help".
(gdb) print $2.__data
$3 = {__lock = 2, __count = 85, __owner = 0, __nusers = 0, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}}
```

Can someone point me to where I can try and understand this struct ? I can see the owner is = 0 but what does that mean ? I see the lock = 2, but what does that mean. And finally why does the thread hang on this lock ? Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Impossible to say anything without the code.  Doesn't VS debugger say which thread owns the mutex?

Comment: Is the call done recursively (does the call stack is "normal")? Is the object still valid?

Comment: Yeah, I understand is hard to reach any conclusion like this, I was just trying to understand what are the usual tools to debug this types of problems and how to go about it.

Comment: Why do you think it does not acquire the lock ? If it hangs it means another thread own the lock. Please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduce the problem.

Comment: Because I have prints before acquiring the locks, and the only print I see its when it hangs :( Is there a way to know which thread is owning the lock when the system is hanging ?

Comment: You should be able to see which threads are running and which are waiting in your debugger.

Comment: @jabaa what if the debugger is saying the owner is 0 ? Do you know how to "parse" that mutex struct, I tried to find some docs but I keep getting lost

Comment: No, I don't know this structure. A [mcve] would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share what the other thread(s) are doing, so it's a bit of a mystery of what's going on.

I am deducing what's happening by looking at the mutex data and the source, libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c.

The lock count is 85, so I suspect another thread is locking the mutex, and not letting it go.  So there's a logic error there.

The lock is owned by thread #2 which I suspect is the thread which has the logic error.

You could debug this by adding a print where you lock and one where you unlock with the thread id.  The other way would be to inspect the code in the suspected area and make sure you have definitive lock and unlock pairs around your critical sections.

I also recommend the practice of reducing your logic to a small practical test case.  That way you can check your logic outside of whatever big thing is you are debugging.